# linux + convert sh script to bash + dose bash support previos sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, redhat

we have a lot of sh scripts and we want to upgrade them to bash scripts

my question:

dose bash support any previous sh script ?

if not what need to know before we convert sh to bash ?
I mean what we need to change/replace in the sh script to be bash script

Comment: Why is the upgrade necessary?

Comment: first we wan to alignment them to bash because some of them are bash ,

Comment: You can invoke the sh interpreter from within Bash and pass code or a script to it.

Comment: you mean to do bash /tmp/script.sh ?

Comment: No, in a Bash shell `$ sh /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: so what is the add value , I want to run it in bash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158048/discussion-between-king-david-and-marekful).

Comment: `bash` is a superset of POSIX `sh`, so if you have POSIX-compliant scripts, then yes, `bash` can run them. (Caveat: `bash`'s implementation of `echo` is not POSIX-compliant by default, so you may need to make some adjustments to get the same results.)

Comment: If you're talking about 1970s-Bourne scripts (not compatible with POSIX sh), there could be behavior like using `^` as a pipe character. Details matter, and this question doesn't really include any. Also, behavior of `set -e` is *wildly* different/incompatible between different POSIX-y/Bourne-family shells; see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have unfortunately seen only a limited number of attempts to convert shell scripts from legacy UNIX platforms to bash.  Usually there were uneventful.

One interesting example I remember was a script which used non-POSIX-conforming expansion behavior for `<<here` documents to implement a `goto`, presumably to simplify porting `.bat` scripts from MS-DOS or Windows.  (The “labels” started with a colon `:`.)  This did not work in bash because it follows POSIX semantics, so here documents could not be used to conditionally remove sections of the shell script.

In practice, the larger issue is often with the programs called from the shell scripts, which can show behavioral differences as well.

So the answer is a rather unsatisfying “it depends”, I'm afraid.